# Replacement for "many" after the noun?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adverbs

I have the following (half-) sentence:

> *This dreadful monotony plagues many classrooms, but (...)*

However, I found this phrasing unsatisfactory, as I would like to avoid using *"many"*, if possible. Is there an alternative phrasing, **preferably one in which the replacement for "many" comes *after* "classrooms"**? Something like *"This dreadful monotony plagues classrooms **beyond number**, but (...)"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before noun, try: *innumerable*, *countless*, *several*, *scores (of)*

Post-positional (after noun) modifiers are uncommon in English. You could try expressions such as "...*the world over*." Other phrasings would seldom be acceptable unless the text allowed for poetic prose; for example, "*This dreadful monotony plagues classrooms innumerate...*"